# Angular matInput

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mat-input

Angular formcontrol works on different matInput, they have the same formControlName but it does not work on the second one. Why is that it works on the first one and not on the second one ? Any idea ? whats the difference ? they are just the same matInput field right ? Thank you.

why is that it does not work when there is  [matAutocomplete]="auto" ? what is the alternative ?

## Firstone (this works) - the input contains the question

```
<input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" formControlName="question">
```

## secondone (this does not load  the question)

```
 <input matInput
              #questionSearch 
              [ngClass]="!hasSelectedQuestion() ? '' : 'hidden'"
              [matAutocomplete]="auto"
              [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
              formControlName="question"
              required
              class="full-width"
            />
```

Comment: can you provide  your typescript code ?

Comment: yes2 , can you please open chat in stackoverflow ? @AymenTAGHLISSIA

Comment: i don't know how

Comment: lets try to add more message to add a room

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA , do you have skype or discord ?

Comment: no but if you want you can send me your code to gmail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211570/discussion-between-aymen-taghlissia-and-mark-luthberg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the probleme is in `[matChipInputFor]="chipList"`, it accepts array element

Comment: so what would be the solution ?

Comment: i think  this Answer  can help  you https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101238/13131286

Comment: can we go on chat in stackoverflow ? I just have to show some code\

Comment: I cant seem to understand the link youve shared

Comment: can you please open a chat in here ?

Comment: can you create a chat now ? so i can join